# SQL query aggregate may not appear

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this two SQL tables:

```
create table Kids (
    id  Int Identity (1,1) primary key not null
    , firstName varchar(100)
    , lastName  varchar(100)
    , birthDate  datetime
)

create table Toys (
    id Int Identity (1,1) primary key not null
    , kidId Int
    , toyName varchar(100)
    , colour varchar(100)
)

ALTER TABLE Toys
ADD FOREIGN KEY (kidId) REFERENCES Kids(id);
```

I am trying to get: all kids under 5 years of age who have more than 1 toy

I have this query:

```
select CONCAT(Kids.firstName,' ',Kids.lastName) as FullName,
birthDate,
count(Toys.Id) as 'Number of Toys'
from Kids
inner join Toys on Kids.id = Toys.kidId
where datediff(year, birthDate, getdate()) <= 5
and count(Toys.Id) > 1
```

But I am getting the error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

A list with the expected results.

Comment: So what is your question? `WHERE` is for pre-aggregation filtering and `HAVING` - for post-aggregation.

Comment: How can I make it work? I do not understand @PM 77-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select concat(Kids.firstName,' ',Kids.lastName) as FullName, birthDate
    , count(Toys.Id) as 'Number of Toys'
from Kids 
inner join Toys on Kids.id = Toys.kidId
where datediff(year, birthDate, getdate()) <= 5
group By Kids.firstName,Kids.lastName,birthDate
having count(Toys.Id) > 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says it clearly you can't put an aggregation function in a where clause only in a having.

Still you need to `GROUP BY` so that every kid appears with his correct count, else you get only q row back

```
select concat(Kids.firstName,' ',Kids.lastName) as FullName,
    birthDate,
    count(Toys.Id) as 'Number of Toys'
from Kids
inner join Toys on Kids.id = Toys.kidId
where datediff(year, birthDate, getdate()) <= 5
group by concat(Kids.firstName,' ',Kids.lastName), birthDate  
having count(Toys.Id) > 1
```

| FullName | birthDate | Number of Toys |
| --- | --- | --- |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NLSPkD_q)